# Code within Mongoose promise never executes

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am currently using Mongoose with my Express application within my controllers. So far, I've been importing the model, and then running queries against it with success. Now, I'm setting up a cron file (called `cron.js`) and have a  file that imports it the same way, however when I run the file from a `package.json` script the code within the promise never executes; there is no return value. This is the code in the script which runs my file:

```
babel-node server/db/cron.js
```

I've tried a few things:

```
import User from '../models/user';

User.find({}, function(err, users)  {
      // these don't run:
      console.log(err);
      console.log(users);
    })

async function getUser() {
    // runs
    console.log('hi');
    let user = await User.findOne({ 'name' : 'ETH'})
    // doesn't run
    console.log(user);
}

getUser();

User.findOne({ name: 'bob' })
.exec((err, user) => {
  // doesn't run
  console.log('123')
}
```

When I `console.log` the model (`User`) and the function (`User.find`) they have been imported succesfully. I've also tried this with `findOne`.

Comment: are there any errors? what version of node and mongoose?

Comment: @TomaszBubała there are no errors, I'm using mongoose 5.0.4 and node 9.5.0, the only thing that the console returns is '✨ Done in 2.08s.'

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.exec()`:

```
let user = await User.findOne({ 'name' : 'ETH'}).exec()
```

`findOne()` returns a `Query` which returns a `Promise` which you then call `.exec()`

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findone_findOne
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec

Comment: I called `exec()` without luck, and I also tried adding a `.then((user) => {}` to `getUser`, and the code inside that didn't run